# Matching and grouping a pattern within another pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, expression

I have the following string:

```
Release Notes</h1>
<h2><a class="anchor" id="subsecRN042"></a>
V0.0.42 (ADK 1.0.1)</h2>
<ul>
<li>Fix for buffer level drop due to interference causing HD to under run </li>
<li>Improve recovery mechanism for HD when buffer level is too low</li>
</ul>
<h2><a class="anchor" id="subsecRN041"></a>
V0.0.41 (ADK 1.0.0)</h2>
<ul>
<li>Resolve issue with writing to MSI area of flash in ATE</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to group the version numbers, for example, one group would contain the following:

```
V0.0.42 (ADK 1.0.1)
```

And then the following groups would contain the release notes, for example, the following groups would contain:

```
Fix for buffer level drop due to interference causing HD to under run
Improve recovery mechanism for HD when buffer level is too low
```

And I'm trying to get this to search and match throughout the entire document.  So finally the end goal would be to have 2-3 groups per match.

Match 1:

```
Group 1 = V0.0.42 (ADK 1.0.1)
Group 2 = Fix for buffer level drop due to interference causing HD to under run, Improve recovery mechanism for HD when buffer level is too low
```

Match 2:

```
Group 1 = V0.0.41 (ADK 1.0.0)
Group 2 = Resolve issue with writing to MSI area of flash in ATE
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?  I've been trying for about 2 hours now, with small amounts of luck.  Getting close, just haven't found the answer.  I have gotten the closest with the following expression:

```
r'^(V.+)</h2>\s<ul>\s((?:<li>.+</li>\s){0,})'
```

But I can't seem to find a way to get rid of the identifiers:

```
<li> and </li>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use regexp? Usually HTML should not be parsed with it.

Comment: Take a look to [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to remove the `<li>` and `<\li>` using regex is likely to mean that only the last section within the `<li>` tags will be captured by the `.+` bit, since the repeating nature means only the last section that fulfils that capturing group requirements will be caught by that capturing group (http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

As such, if you'd like to stick with using regex for the first stage, either a string.replace, (e.g: `regexResult.replace('<li>','')` ) might work, or the re module's re.split (e.g. `re.split('<\/*li>',regexResult)` ) to produce multiple strings?

EDIT: For clarification, the first paragraph was considering a regex such as `^(V.+)</h2>\s<ul>\s((?:<li>(.+)</li>\s){0,})` or similar, which treated `(.+)` as a capturing group

Comment: This showed me that I had a wrong understanding of how regex matching worked.  Thanks for the insight.